# Merfolk Laws And Government

Tags: society, culture, underwater, merfolk, species

Recently, I saw [this](https://tamiart.tumblr.com/image/155448393927) image, and later, [this](https://tamiart.tumblr.com/post/134938786527/color-concept-sketches-for-mermaid-houses) image, which inspired me to think about the culture of merpeople. I've got quite a lot worked out, but I'd appreciate hearing other's ideas. In particular, I'm looking about laws and government, and how they might vary from our own.

Some crucial aspects about the merfolk are

- Human-level of intelligence
- Near the human level of technology (exception is medicine)
- Magic is rare but not nonexistent. The types of magic are controlling air, controlling heat, and healing.
- Interactions with humans only happen once every couple of months and are mainly trading. The relationships from one species government to another are not hostile nor exactly friendly. The people are very interested in the other species.
- The merfolk have a society that is very focused on equality.
- Their eyes, nose, teeth, and hair are all designed for an underwater environment. Their hair isn't even hair, it just appears like it, and is used for mothers to carry their young. It can move independently.
- The subspecies of merpeople are (along with the generic merfolk)

  ```
   Tropical
       Reef
       Island
   Coastal
       Coldwater coastal (mainly European)
       Warmwater coastal (only live in water that is warm year-round)
       Estuarian
   Freshwater
       River
       Lake
       Waterfalls
       Swamp
   Kelp Forest
  ```

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and read through the [help]. We cannot answer questions which require writing a book to be answered.

Comment: Whilst your edit is splendid, it doesn't help clarify what you need. As the [help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) says, questions:: *"Must be specific and answerable: What problem are you trying to solve?"*. Fishing for ideas sort of open-ended questions don't really work in our format. By all means though, write into the question your specific area of concern, then we can probably help. Welcome to WB.se

Comment: Basically what the others are saying is: break this down into about fifty manageable queries! Given that you're so inspired to work on your own Merfolk, I think you'll do well here --- looks like you've got a lot of material to work with as foundations for your questions!

Comment: Okay, thanks! Let me see...

Comment: I re-added a piece of the original text. Is that any better?

Comment: Seriously, you've asked about over 40 areas of the society. Just focus on *one* at a time, you can then ask questions in separate threads linked to the first question with full details in. Each new question can include tweaks and adjustments from what you've decided after reading answers to your previous questions. See for example: [1](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/35929/from-mice-to-men-series), [2](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37046/does-any-microorganism-lend-itself-to-domestication-series) Cont.

Comment: Cont. [3](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37450/what-could-microscopic-people-use-for-fire-series), [4](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37639/would-primitive-weaponry-be-useful-when-scaled-down-to-microscopic-size-serie), [5](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/37529/what-tiny-animals-pose-a-threat-to-the-survival-of-microscopic-humanoids-serie) (and there's more if you search). They're not linked, but there is a clear thread. I recommend you pick a starting point to ask about.

Comment: Okay, I think I understand now. Thanks for your help!

Comment: I've cast a vote to have the question reopened as I think there's enough to go on for some answers to happen, it may take a few hours for all the votes to come in before answers are forthcoming, so sit back and plan your next questions in the series;)

Comment: Oh, thank you so much!

Comment: I also voted to reopen this question.

Comment: @Tantalus'touch. It's been a little while. Is there anything I should do or just wait?